# How can a harmonic constraint be added between two groups in one direction using NAMD?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, namd, enhanced-sampling

As a new user of NAMD, I am seeking assistance regarding a specific task. I intend to pull a LIGAND from outside to the center of a lipid using NAMD. To achieve this, I have utilized the colvar module with the distance option to measure the separation between two distinct groups: the center of mass of LIGAND and as well the center of mass molecules in the center of the lipid.

In my attempts to exert control over this process, I have employed a harmonic constraint. However, I have encountered an issue where the LIGAND exhibits movement in multiple directions, contrary to my intention of restricting its motion to a single axis, similar to the pull code in GROMACS.

Thus, I am inquiring whether there exists a method within NAMD to confine the axis along which the distance between these two groups decreases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try steered molecular dynamics (SMD) for this task. Let's say that you have a ligand and an interaction center. You can write out a new PDB file where you set the occupancy of the ligand atoms to a non-zero number. Then you can enable SMD and give this new PDB file as an input, and the pull direction and the pull velocity. For further information please see this [link](https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/namd/2.9/ug/node48.html).

Original PDB file

```
REMARK original generated coordinate pdb file
ATOM      1  N   ARG A   1      -3.903  -0.715  10.177  1.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM      2  HT1 ARG A   1      -4.767  -0.149  10.323  1.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM      3  HT2 ARG A   1      -3.899  -0.959   9.163  1.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM      4  HT3 ARG A   1      -3.865  -1.545  10.788  1.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM      5  CA  ARG A   1      -2.758   0.230  10.362  1.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM      6  HA  ARG A   1      -2.778   0.610  11.374  1.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM      7  CB  ARG A   1      -1.421  -0.522  10.066  1.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM      8  HB1 ARG A   1      -1.355  -1.413  10.729  1.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM      9  HB2 ARG A   1      -1.434  -0.874   9.009  1.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     10  CG  ARG A   1      -0.139   0.320  10.276  1.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     11  HG1 ARG A   1      -0.168   1.193   9.583  1.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     12  HG2 ARG A   1      -0.133   0.715  11.316  1.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     13  CD  ARG A   1       1.150  -0.455   9.991  1.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     14  HD1 ARG A   1       1.243  -1.319  10.687  1.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     15  HD2 ARG A   1       1.149  -0.807   8.932  1.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     16  NE  ARG A   1       2.293   0.489  10.200  1.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     17  CZ  ARG A   1       3.569   0.161  10.024  1.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     18  NH1 ARG A   1       3.924  -1.052   9.653  1.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     19 HH11 ARG A   1       4.880  -1.272   9.513  1.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     20 HH12 ARG A   1       3.208  -1.716   9.484  1.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     21  NH2 ARG A   1       4.511   1.061  10.219  1.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     22 HH21 ARG A   1       5.463   0.811  10.090  1.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     23 HH22 ARG A   1       4.259   1.980  10.500  1.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     24  C   ARG A   1      -2.953   1.434   9.416  1.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     25  OT1 ARG A   1      -3.891   1.378   8.575  1.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     26  OT2 ARG A   1      -2.184   2.415   9.548  1.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     27  N   ARG     1      -3.989  -0.713   0.193  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     28  HT1 ARG     1      -4.846  -0.133   0.328  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     29  HT2 ARG     1      -3.991  -0.983  -0.814  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     30  HT3 ARG     1      -3.960  -1.528   0.825  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     31  CA  ARG     1      -2.831   0.222   0.350  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     32  HA  ARG     1      -2.843   0.628   1.352  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     33  CB  ARG     1      -1.506  -0.555   0.070  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     34  HB1 ARG     1      -1.449  -1.429   0.755  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     35  HB2 ARG     1      -1.526  -0.932  -0.978  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     36  CG  ARG     1      -0.212   0.276   0.254  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     37  HG1 ARG     1      -0.232   1.132  -0.461  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     38  HG2 ARG     1      -0.197   0.697   1.284  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     39  CD  ARG     1       1.066  -0.522  -0.016  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     40  HD1 ARG     1       1.151  -1.370   0.702  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     41  HD2 ARG     1       1.057  -0.901  -1.065  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     42  NE  ARG     1       2.222   0.412   0.167  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     43  HE  ARG     1       2.026   1.368   0.370  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     44  CZ  ARG     1       3.493   0.063  -0.005  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     45  NH1 ARG     1       3.831  -1.163  -0.346  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     46 HH11 ARG     1       4.784  -1.398  -0.485  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     47 HH12 ARG     1       3.106  -1.822  -0.497  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     48  NH2 ARG     1       4.447   0.956   0.164  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     49 HH21 ARG     1       5.395   0.690   0.038  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     50 HH22 ARG     1       4.208   1.884   0.422  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     51  C   ARG     1      -3.015   1.404  -0.625  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     52  OT1 ARG     1      -3.956   1.338  -1.461  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     53  OT2 ARG     1      -2.233   2.378  -0.520  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
END
```

SMDFile

```
CRYST1    0.000    0.000    0.000  90.00  90.00  90.00 P 1           1
ATOM      1  N   ARG A   1      -3.903  -0.715  10.177  0.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM      2  HT1 ARG A   1      -4.767  -0.149  10.323  0.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM      3  HT2 ARG A   1      -3.899  -0.959   9.163  0.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM      4  HT3 ARG A   1      -3.865  -1.545  10.788  0.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM      5  CA  ARG A   1      -2.758   0.230  10.362  0.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM      6  HA  ARG A   1      -2.778   0.610  11.374  0.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM      7  CB  ARG A   1      -1.421  -0.522  10.066  0.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM      8  HB1 ARG A   1      -1.355  -1.413  10.729  0.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM      9  HB2 ARG A   1      -1.434  -0.874   9.009  0.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     10  CG  ARG A   1      -0.139   0.320  10.276  0.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     11  HG1 ARG A   1      -0.168   1.193   9.583  0.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     12  HG2 ARG A   1      -0.133   0.715  11.316  0.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     13  CD  ARG A   1       1.150  -0.455   9.991  0.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     14  HD1 ARG A   1       1.243  -1.319  10.687  0.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     15  HD2 ARG A   1       1.149  -0.807   8.932  0.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     16  NE  ARG A   1       2.293   0.489  10.200  0.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     17  CZ  ARG A   1       3.569   0.161  10.024  0.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     18  NH1 ARG A   1       3.924  -1.052   9.653  0.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     19 HH11 ARG A   1       4.880  -1.272   9.513  0.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     20 HH12 ARG A   1       3.208  -1.716   9.484  0.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     21  NH2 ARG A   1       4.511   1.061  10.219  0.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     22 HH21 ARG A   1       5.463   0.811  10.090  0.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     23 HH22 ARG A   1       4.259   1.980  10.500  0.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     24  C   ARG A   1      -2.953   1.434   9.416  0.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     25  OT1 ARG A   1      -3.891   1.378   8.575  0.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     26  OT2 ARG A   1      -2.184   2.415   9.548  0.00  0.00      ARG   
ATOM     27  N   ARG A   1      -3.989  -0.713   0.193  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     28  HT1 ARG A   1      -4.846  -0.133   0.328  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     29  HT2 ARG A   1      -3.991  -0.983  -0.814  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     30  HT3 ARG A   1      -3.960  -1.528   0.825  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     31  CA  ARG A   1      -2.831   0.222   0.350  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     32  HA  ARG A   1      -2.843   0.628   1.352  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     33  CB  ARG A   1      -1.506  -0.555   0.070  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     34  HB1 ARG A   1      -1.449  -1.429   0.755  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     35  HB2 ARG A   1      -1.526  -0.932  -0.978  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     36  CG  ARG A   1      -0.212   0.276   0.254  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     37  HG1 ARG A   1      -0.232   1.132  -0.461  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     38  HG2 ARG A   1      -0.197   0.697   1.284  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     39  CD  ARG A   1       1.066  -0.522  -0.016  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     40  HD1 ARG A   1       1.151  -1.370   0.702  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     41  HD2 ARG A   1       1.057  -0.901  -1.065  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     42  NE  ARG A   1       2.222   0.412   0.167  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     43  HE  ARG A   1       2.026   1.368   0.370  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     44  CZ  ARG A   1       3.493   0.063  -0.005  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     45  NH1 ARG A   1       3.831  -1.163  -0.346  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     46 HH11 ARG A   1       4.784  -1.398  -0.485  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     47 HH12 ARG A   1       3.106  -1.822  -0.497  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     48  NH2 ARG A   1       4.447   0.956   0.164  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     49 HH21 ARG A   1       5.395   0.690   0.038  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     50 HH22 ARG A   1       4.208   1.884   0.422  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     51  C   ARG A   1      -3.015   1.404  -0.625  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     52  OT1 ARG A   1      -3.956   1.338  -1.461  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
ATOM     53  OT2 ARG A   1      -2.233   2.378  -0.520  1.00  0.00      ARG1  
END
```

NAMD Input Section

```
SMD           on
SMDFile       merged_smd.pdb
SMDk          1.0
SMDVel        0.005
SMDDir        {0 0 1}
SMDOutputFreq $restartFreq
```

I am not sure about the format for SMDDir, but you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: First of all, Thanks for your comment. Can you provide the template input with any pdb and I will adapt the input to my system. In SMD, Do I need to define the center of the lipid? How can I control the move of the LIG to the center of lipid

Comment: @Abd-ElazeemMohamed I have added a file.

Comment: Ok. I understand you. One question, now if the distance between my ligand and the center of the lipid is 75 A so how can I confirm that there ligand will move this distance to the center of the lipid because I was doing umbrella sampling.

Comment: ```SMDDir        {0 0 1}``` means that the ligand will move away form the site in the +z direction, and if you use ```SMDDir        {0 0 -1}``` it will move towards the site in the -z direction.

Comment: If you are doing umbrella sampling, you can specify the direction of motion in the control section of the collars file. if you are **doing** umbrella sampling, do not do SMD along with that.

Comment: Ok. This is my question. How can I specify the direction of motion in the colvars file?

Comment: Please post that as a separate question

Comment: Ok, I posted a new question